# How do i change the property of javascript wirtten text?

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to know how can I change the `document.write(c)` property(color, size, etc.) later on. Is it possible to somehow access that printed line again? I do not want to regenerate all the words again.

```
function genWords(size){
    for(var i =0; i < 10000; i++){
        document.write(Os.fontsize(size));  
        if(i == theC) document.write(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. If you want to apply styles, you should be adding nodes to the DOM.

Comment: then what should i use?

Comment: The entirety of the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `document.write`, you should use something like

`document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += c`

then you can style it via

`document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style[<attribute>] = <value>`
if you want to use pure javascript.
Otherwise you can make some stylesheet for the body tag.